# Is it possible to override the tax calculated by Quickbooks Desktop when using IDS to POST an Invoice?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are integrating our order management application with Quickbooks Desktop using IDS. We are finding that the tax calculated by our application is different by a few pennies to the tax calculated by Quickbooks. Is there any way to override the tax calculated by Quickbooks when we do an Invoice POST?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would set the items as non-taxable and then add a line item that references the tax item and you can set the amount when added. However, it looks like IDS is NOT writing back the Taxable field in v2 (Cannot be written to QuickBooks.)

You should be able to change the tax code on the item to no-tax and then use the TaxLine to add the tax at the value you want.

William

Comment: I tried setting the item to non-taxable and passing a tax amount in the tax line, but the tax amount is completely ignored. The invoice is created with zero tax.